# Can I see my Track Record for suggested edit reviews?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-history

In the review history for suggested edits, I can see what I voted on each of the edits I reviewed.

Is there a way to see which were approved/rejected vs my own vote?

I want to get an idea of my ratio of correct to incorrect reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Data Explorer for that.

Giles already created a query for that: [*My overruled suggested edit reviews*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79859/my-overruled-suggested-edit-reviews). Take into account that the data is up to a week old; the data is refreshed every Sunday.

Looking at your Stack Overflow userid, I see [no disputed reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79859/my-overruled-suggested-edit-reviews); you have so far voted exactly what the consensus turned out to be. That's not that surprising, since all but one of your reviews were done *after* the last data update. You should get more meaningful data after the next data update.